# igraph: identifying nodes linking two subgraphs in igraph (R)

Tags: r, social-networking, igraph

I have a list of networks of family names. Each network is composed of two different subgraphs (for instance, `net_277_278` is composed of subgraphs `sg_277` and `sg_278`). (I induced the subgraphs using a complicated mix of the `gsub` and `induced_subgraph` functions).

All the edges in the same subgraph have the form `Johnson_278--Smith_278`, indicating a link between two surnames belonging to the same subgraph. Links between the two subgraphs are given by the same surname (but have a different subscript). A link between the two subgraphs looks like this: `Johnson_277--Johnson_278`.

For each subgraph, I want to to compute some network measures (e.g., centrality), but only for the nodes that are directly connected to the other subgraph. (Note that I do not want to induce new subgraphs, since this would alter the measures). For instance, for `sg_277` I would like to compute some measures only for `Johnson_277`, if that's the only node with a link to the `sg_278`.

As a small example, this is one of the networks:

`net[10] #277_278
    $11_277_278
    IGRAPH UN-- 9 6 -- 
    + attr: name (v/c)
    + edges (vertex names):
    [1] SANCHEZ_110277--SANCHEZ_110278 SANCHEZ_110277--PANTOJA_110277    SANCHEZ_110278--GALVAN_110278 
    [4] PEREZ_110278  --VEGA_110278    PEREZ_110278  --OLVERA_110278     PATIÑO_110278 --SERRANO_110278`

[Graphically, it looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fM7oF.png)

And this is one of the subgraphs:

```
sgraph1[[10]] #277
IGRAPH UN-- 2 1 -- 
+ attr: name (v/c)
+ edge (vertex names):
[1] SANCHEZ_110277--PANTOJA_110277
```

In this case, I would like to run the function for eigenvector centrality `(evcent(sgraph1[[10]])$vector)`, only for the nodes linking the two subgraphs (in this case, just `SANCHEZ_110277`, which, as can be seen in the full network, has a link to `SANCHEZ_110278`.

Is there a way to do this? I have been trying stuff using regular expressions, `neighbors` and `ego()` functions but none of these seem to help.

Comment: Please provide a [small working example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) people can use to start tinkering.

Comment: Can you post what you have tried with regular expressions?  A proper regular expression filtering of the nodes should do the trick.

Comment: If I did the following, I would be able to extract the numbers of the subscripts from the list of edges and then identify the nodes with a different subscript:

    `foo <- E(net[[5]]) 
     gsub("^[A-Z]+_([0-9]+).*","\\1",foo)
     gsub(".*_([0-9]+)$","\\1",bar)`

The problem is that ` E(net[[5]]) ` is not a vector but an igraph object (can't get rid of the header that says:

` 148/148 edges (vertex names)`

Comment: You could apply that gsub function to the edge list.  Something like,
    `get.num=function(x){ gsub("^[A-Z]+_([0-9]+).*","\\1",x)}
    apply(get.edgelist(net[[5]]),2,get.num)`
and then identify the rows that are not duplicated.